# Where to initialize a NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c

having an issue using a NSMutableArray;

In my implementation file applicationDidFinishLaunching method I have

```
_imgArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

and _imgArray is defined in my .h file as

```
NSMutableArray *_imgArray;
```

After populating it, it traces out correctly.

The problem is, in another method in my implementation file, I can't seem to acces the _imgArray array.
It traces out to

```
_imgArray=  ar.lproj
```

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised you're not crashing. You aren't retaining the array when you assign it to _imgArray, so by the second event loop, it's pointing to unallocated memory.

Don't mess with your ivars directly. Use accessors (@property). And study the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html).

Comment: Yep needed to retain it. Thanks!